# Cannot access variable inside class scope

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, nuxt.js

I am writing custom auth scheme with nuxt.js and I have an issue with accessing a variable.

I am injecting `fs` object into the scheme, and it is available in `_setupFirestore`

The plan is to assign it to global `fireStore` variable so I can access it inside class, but for some reason `fireStore` inside class is `null`

```
import LocalScheme from '@nuxtjs/auth/lib/schemes/local'

let fireStore = null
export const _setupFirestore = (fs) => {
  console.log('setup')
  fireStore = fs
  console.log(fireStore) // correct object
}

export default class CustomScheme extends LocalScheme {
  mounted() {
    console.log(fireStore) // null
  }
}
```

Any idea why that would happen?

Comment: where (and how) do you call the _setupFirestore ?

Comment: @CosimoChellini I call _setupFirestore from the plugin like this:


`import { _setupFirestore } from '@/schemes/customScheme.js'

export default ({ app, env, store }, inject) => {
  _setupFirestore(app.$fireStore)
}`

Comment: are you sure this plugin is called correctly ?

Comment: @CosimoChellini yes, I can access fs inside _setupFirestore but not in CustomScheme